# api in r - Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE

Tags: r

Hello.

 I am trying to pull some data with this function...

```
orats <- function(data="cores/general",tickers,token){
  t1 = paste(tickers,sep=",")
  x1 = GET(paste("https://api.orats.io/data/",data,"?ticker=",t1,sep=""),add_headers(Authorization=token))
  x2 = content(x1)[[1]]
  data.frame(t(sapply(x2, function(x) x[1:max(lengths(x2))])))
}
```

All is well. However, for the tickers argument I have to write it as:

```
tickers <- "AAPL,MSFT"
```

Whenever I try to use use a vector where the characters are separated, it doesn't work.
For example:

```
tickers <- c("AAPL","MSFT")
~runs code~

Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

I have read most of the posts containing this error, but I haven't found a working solution. For flexibility, I wonder how can I make this function work with my second example [ie. tickers<-c("AAPL","MSFT")].

 Thanks.

Comment: You're using `sep = ","` when you should be using `collapse = ","`.  The `collapse` argument is used for consolidating a single vector with multiple elements, while `sep` is for "cross-pasting" multiple vectors "against each other". If you use `sep`, you get not `"AAPL,MSFT"` but rather a vector `c("AAPL", "MSFT")` — `tickers` cross-pasted against nothing — whose multiple are cross-pasted once again against the rest of the `url`. The result is the vector `c("https://api.orats.io/data/...?ticker=AAPL", "https://api.orats.io/data/?...ticker=MSFT")`, whose length of 2 throws the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use sep but collapse in paste:

```
tickers <- c("AAPL", "MSFT")
t1 = paste(tickers, sep = ",")
t1
[1] "AAPL" "MSFT"

t1 = paste(tickers, collapse = ",")
t1
[1] "AAPL,MSFT"
```